# ArgMax problem with Piecewise function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm having an issue with finding the maximizer of a very simple piecewise function.

```
c = 0.125;

ArgMax[{Piecewise[{{0.5 (1 - c/(2 r) - (-2 - c + 2 r )/(
        2 (-2 + r))), r == 1}}], 0 <= r <= 1}, r]
```

gives the result 0.641915, which is obviously not true since at r=1 the value of the function is strictly positive. Why am I having this problem?

Comment: use exact numbers: `c = 1/8` and `1/2` instead of `0.5`.